# dict update not working but printing same dict works

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have created a dict and want to use some of it's values as key for another dict.
Source dict:

```py
{
    "Index": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
    ]
}
```

When I do:

```
print({list(*dict_source.values())[index] : "1"})
```

it works
But if I do:

```
dict2.update({list(*dict_source.values())[index] : "1"})
```

it doesn't work.

What is the issue here?
Expected output:
dict2

```
    {
      "A": 1,
      "B": 2,
      "C": 3,
      "some random value": 5
    }
```

**index in list is for a loop that I'm using to get 1,2,3 value.

```
for index, _ in enumerate(<some 3 element list>):
```

Comment: Do you want to use a specific value? like `Index : "A"`

Comment: It would be helpful if you could clarify more what is the behavior you expect 

Comment: I get following error
dict2.update({list(*dict_source.values())[index] : "1"})
TypeError: list expected at most 1 argument, got 2

Comment: added more details.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
dict_source = {"Index": ["A", "B", "C"]}
index = 0
print({tuple(list(dict_source.values())[index]) : "1"})
dict2 = {}
dict2.update({tuple(list(dict_source.values())[index]) : "1"})
print(dict2)
```

Here is the result.

```
{('A', 'B', 'C'): '1'}
{('A', 'B', 'C'): '1'}
```

It seems that your code tries to use a list, which is mutable, as a key of a dictionary. Replacing the list with a tuple should solve the problem.

Comment: I added more details in question.

Comment: changing to tuple like you did won't help as it's first getting converted into a list. I tried with list.copy also. didn't work.